# Using Checkstyle to build models of source code

Tags: java, checkstyle

I would like to find out if I can invoke some internal APIs from **Checkstyle** to access the model of the source code that it builds. Ideally, I would like to use that models to perform my own analysis.

Comment: Sure you can. [Custom checks](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/writingchecks.html) have full access to the model.

Comment: So could I use Custom checks to export the whole model?

Comment: Absolutely. However, if you are just interested in the model, do consider using [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/) instead. That's what Checkstyle is doing internally.

Comment: Well, ANTLR is a great tool for parsing but after parsing you have to do symbol resolution and that is not easy. You have to consider also the jars in the classpaths and things like that. By the way I would use Javaparser if it was just about parsing (I am contributing to that project)